# I have 10 UIView with setTags how to work with a given UIView at a given tag?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I set a "view"'s rect at a given tag of say "5"?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the view with the given tag using the method [`viewWithTag:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW26) of the class `UIView`.

```
UIView *viewWithTag5 = [self.view viewWithTag:5];
viewWithTag5.frame = rect;
```

Comment: So assuming your views are subviews of `self.view`, you could set the frame with `[self.view viewWithTag:5].frame = CGRectMake(...)`